# exposition--meaning

Tags: meaning

Since school, I was always familiar with the definition of: an opening or an introduction to something (e.g. a story).

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exposition

Only yesterday, I found out that there's a totally different definition for it: "a clear and full explanation of an idea or theory."

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exposition

What's peculiar here is that both definitions from two different dictionaries are totally different(?)

---

More specifically, in the context of reviewing a paper, what does it mean: "Clarity of Exposition?" Does it refer only to the introduction or the full explanation of an idea or theory? They probably mean clarity of presentation (of the full paper).

Comment: Don't they both mention explain or explanation? Cambridge secondarily says that an exposition is a show, convention, *expo*. With a *shoresh* of **expose**, meaning show, exposition is explaining (to show and persuade) and presenting a gala show.

Comment: In the first, it means an opening or an introduction to something. In the second, it means a clear and full explanation of an idea or theory.

Comment: Cambridge starts with "a setting forth of the meaning or purpose (as of a writing)". I would call setting an idea forward to be *presenting* that idea—a presentation. A fancy exhibit is a presentation, too. In real life, though, I hear *expository writing* to mean persuasive material, while *exposition* is reserved to mean an event ("the Eiffel Tower during the 1889 Exposition").

Comment: *I was always familiar with the definition of: an opening or an introduction to something* That would be the **opening/introductory** exposition". *I found a totally different definition for it*: "a clear and full explanation of an idea or theory." -- That would be "an exposition of the idea". As the OED says *4b. A statement in which **any** matter is set forth in detail.*

Comment: @Yosef Baskin, actually, exposition comes from exposit, which is different from expose and gives a better interpretation to exposition.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I am not familiar with the word "*shoresh*" which you use and italicize in your comment above. What is the meaning of this word, please? An online search suggests that this is a Hebrew word meaning "root". Normally non-English words should not be used in answers or comments here on ELL, except when one is writing **about** such words and how they are used in English, or have influenced English. Of course English has  famously adopted a great many words from other languages, and those can and should be used or mentioned when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think `exposition` can have distinct specialized meanings not to be confused with each other:

1. In **Literature**, the meaning you're familiar with (see [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exposition)):

   > Exposition in a written work is the passages which explain where events take place, what happened before the story begins, and the background of the characters.
2. In **Scholarly work** (from [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exposition)):

   > a clear and full explanation of an idea or theory

   Example (from Cambridge English Corpus):

   > Both writers' works contain expositions of the theory of justification by faith alone, a doctrine the king abhorred.
3. In **Music** (from [Merriam-Webster meaning 2b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exposition)), the meaning I'm familiar with, where in the exposition section we can hear the theme of the sonata / fugue very clearly after which the theme is fragmented / transposed / inverted / rearranged / recombined / etc. in the subsequent development section (see [this video explaining the Sonata Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzHS7QL-B-c&t=31s)):

   > (1): the first part of a musical composition in sonata form in which the thematic material of the movement is presented
   >
   > (2): the opening section of a fugue
4. In **Rubric for reviewing a paper** ([*Source*](http://jennifermmorton.com/plunkettrubric.pdf)), which is **your question**, one criteria of evaluation is:

   > **Clarity of Exposition & Definitions**: Do you understand the concepts and use them properly? Have you clearly explained the issues at hand?
5. In **Business** (usually shortened to "expo"):

   > a show in which industrial goods, works of art, etc. are shown to the public
6. Etc.

From the above, it seems all meanings share 2 elements: **clarity of presentation** and **explanation of idea**.